# Is it possible to increment the maximum row size in AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bigdata, amazon-athena

I'm running this query with AWS Athena:

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM "db"."tbl1" t1
INNER JOIN "tbl1"."ema" ea ON
  ea.id = concat(t1.numc,t1.nummt)
WHERE
  ea.cod1 = '23' and
  ea.cod2 = '776'
```

And getting this error:

```
Size of a single row or its columns cannot exceed 32 MB
```

The table is saved in AWS S3 in jsonl format.

It's possible to increase the maximun row size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Athena does not currently let you configure any Presto details.

Comment: Linking the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/other-notable-limitations.html for reference.